# How to create .so file using GCC

Tags: c++, gcc

I want to create a `.so` file for c++ class. I have create a `.h` file and `.cpp` file which named as Hello.h and Hello.cpp. I'm writing a command in terminal use to create .so file but I get the following errors:

> Hello.cpp:2:17: error: jni.h: No such file or directory
>   Hello.h:15: error: ‘JNIEXPORT’ does not name a type
>   Hello.cpp:12: error: ‘jstring’ does not name a type

I would like to ask how to create a .so file using correct command code.

My command code such like bellow:

```
g++ Hello.cpp -o Hello.o
```

Comment: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Comment: this can probably be solved by reading the appropriate documentation for the gnu c/c++ compiler.

Comment: Some `-I` arguments to `g++` are missing (to tell the location of JNI include directory). And you should also pass `-Wall` to `g++`  (to get all warnings)

Comment: Also, learn how to use [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html)

Comment: While those are great suggestions, reading a one liner off of stack overflow is very beneficial for the hundreds that have fallen upon this question. I don't see a problem with it. Referring to hundred page guides could answer countless of the top questions on stack overflow that we use everyday (although the first link isn't necessarily that long).

Comment: You seem to be using JNI, make sure the options to include and link it are specified or remove refsToIt. Also `hello.o` will be an executable elf file, not an object file use `-c` to create an object (`.o`) file, use the `-shared` option to create a `.so` (shared object) file, proper project structure is to use a Makefile to build and first build your C++ files as objects before linking them together (basically pass the .o files in the same way you would a .cpp file), normally I would just explain the `-shared` but based on what little info I got I can tell there are some under the hood issues

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
g++ -fpic -m32 -c Hello.cpp 
g++ -m32 -shared Hello.o
```

-m32 flag is for 32bit build on a 64bit system. But I think your problem may be with your JNI created header file.

Comment: Thank you. But I have try this command it still get the same error.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to build something with JNI. How did you go about doing this? Did you build your interface in java first then use JNI to create the header for your cpp project? You have have to specify where your jni.h header file is by passing in the directory with the -I compiler flag. you also have to include the jni generated header file in your cpp project.